# Need help with this problem about continuous homogeneous function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb {R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Assume that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $r$, $r \gt 0$, that is:

$$f(t\textbf{x}) = t^{r}f(\textbf{x}), \ \ \ \ \  \forall \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d, \ \ \  \forall t \in [0, \infty ].$$

Show that if $f(\textbf{x}) \gt \ 0 \ \ \ \  \forall \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d/\{0\}$, then

$$f({x}) \ge c |\textbf{x}|^r \ \ \ \forall \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

for some $c \gt 0$ where $|\textbf{x}|$ is the magnitude (ie Euclidean length or norm) of vector $\textbf{x}$.

I'm told compactness is important here but I'm unable to understand how.

Answer (score 4):

Let $K=\{x \in \mathbb R^d: |x| \le 1\}$. K is compact. Hence there is $x_0 \in K$ with $f(x) \ge f(x_0)>0$  for all $ x \in K$

Now take $x \in \mathbb R^d$ with $x \ne 0$. Then $\frac{x}{|x|} \in K$. Therfore

$\frac{1}{|x|^r} f(x)=f(\frac{x}{|x|}) \ge f(x_0)$

Comment: Could you explain why $f(x) \geq f(x_0) > 0$ is necessarily true? I get that $f(K)$ is compact by virtue of $K$ being compact, and thus an $x_0$ satisfying $f(x) > f(x_0)$ for all $x\in K$ must exist. But how do we know that $f(x_0) > 0$? It only says that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^d - \{0\}$. In fact, shouldn't $f(0) = 0$ since $f$ is homogenous--otherwise we'd have that $f(0) = f(0\cdot5) = 5^rf(0)$ and $f(0) = f(0\cdot10) = 10^rf(0)$. And thus $x_0 = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to estimate $f $ on the unit ball, using compactness continuity and positivity. Observe that for every $x\in \mathbb {R}^n $ there exists $t\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $x/t $ belongs to the unit ball. Now put together to obtain the estimate.