# Continuous Homogenous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This question has already been asked a few years ago, but I didn't understand the answer fully so I replied to the person who answered it, only to find out their account is suspended.

For a homogenous function $f$ of degree $r > 0$ satisfying that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, then there exists some $c > 0$ satisfying that $f(x) \geq c\lvert x\rvert^r$

I had a similar idea to the answer. Take the set $U = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d : \vert x\rvert \leq 1\}$ .  This is closed and bounded and thus compact, so $f(U)$ is compact and therefore contains its $\inf$ and $\sup$, say $\inf f(U) = f(x_0)$.
Thus, for all $x\in U$, we have $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$, and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d - U$
$$
f(x) \geq \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert ^r} f(x) \geq f\left(\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\right) \geq f(x_0)
$$
Where the last inequality holds since ${x\over\lvert x\rvert}\in K$. Thus, $f(x) \geq f(x_0)\cdot\lvert x\rvert^r$

Then, assuming $f(x_0) > 0$, just let $c = f(x_0)$

My issue lies here, though. Clearly, $0\in U$. And, I claim that $f(0) = 0$, and thus $f(0) = \inf U$ since $f(x) > 0$ for all non-zero $x$. I claim that $f(0) = 0$, since we get the following equalities
$$
f(0) = f(5\cdot 0) = 5^rf(0)\\
f(0) = f(10\cdot 0) = 10^rf(0) 
$$
Since we know that that $r>0$, $5^r f(0) = 10^rf(0)$ is true iff $f(0) = 0$.

This is where I am stuck. How do we remedy this issue?

Edit: Here's the [link to the original post referenced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035494/need-help-with-this-problem-about-continuous-homogeneous-function)

Comment: Evidently you have $$\inf_{x\in U}f(x) = \min \Bigg\{f(0),\inf_{x\in U \\ x\neq 0} f(x)\Bigg\}=0$$ So, your proof involving the set $U$ doesn't work. Have you considered redefining $U$ to be the set $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$? Also, the statement should read "there is some $c>0$ such that $f(x)>c\|x\|^r$ for all $x\neq 0$"

Comment: Please edit a link to the earlier question into the body of your post.

Comment: @MatthewH. I can't believe I missed that, thank you so much! Also, you were right that I got the statement wrong (I updated it just now) but it's still supposed to be for all $x$, but it should be $\geq$ instead of $>$.